# A remainder when $2^{100}$ is divided by $153$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What will be the remainder when $2^{100}$ is divided by $153$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is notable that $153 = 3 \times 3 \times 17$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619). If it were up to me I would instaclose this as a duplicate, but I have promised not to. Instead, I may downvote answers by experienced users unless their answer brings up something unusual.